# What does "!$@" mean in Perl?

Tags: perl

I don't know Perl.  I'm trying to read some Perl code that I didn't write, and I've been stuck for a day or two on this line:

```
use constant RUNTIME => eval "use Time::SoFar qw( runinterval )" || !$@;
```

I've managed to piece together most of it, but I can't figure out the last bit, `!$@`.

This isn't contained in any of the tutorials I've read, and it isn't clear what page of documentation I should look for, since I don't know any keywords related to whatever this is.

Web searching for random symbols gives no results, since most search engines ignore them (including Stack Overflow's, evidently).

I can't break this down into simpler components, either.  I recognize `$` and `@` as sigils for scalar and array variables, but that's clearly not how they're being used here.  Searching for them individually only gives results for these variable sigils.

I need an expert, then.  What does `!$@` mean in this context?

Comment: [`perlvar`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar) is the page for deciphering random symbols

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it looks rather like a censored swear word, it actually breaks down into `!` and `$@`.

Perl has a number of "special variables" which have single-character names; they also have longer names enabled with the directive `use English;`

You can find a list on [the perlvar page of the perl manual](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar) (should also be available by running `perldoc perlvar`), which specifies `$@`, English name `$EVAL_ERROR`, as:

> The Perl error from the last eval operator, i.e. the last exception that was caught. For eval BLOCK, this is either a runtime error message or the string or reference die was called with. The eval STRING form also catches syntax errors and other compile time exceptions.
>
> If no error occurs, eval sets $@ to the empty string.

This is then passed to `!`, which is the "not" operator, which is going to treat the string in `$@` as a boolean.

- If the error string is empty, it will be false, "not false" is true, which will become "1"
- If the error string is *not* empty, it will be true, "not true" is false, which will become ""

Answer (score 3):

`!` is the negation operator ([perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop)), `$@` is the special variable that holds the last exception thrown ([perlvar#$@](http://p3rl.org/perlvar#$@)).

The constant `RUNTIME` will be set to `1` if the `use` clause was executed successfully. Otherwise, it will be set to the empty string.

Answer (score 3):

`$@` is a variable. It's [documented in perlvar](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#$@). It contains the exception that was thrown by the most recent `eval`, or `undef` if there was none. `!` is just the not operator.

Answer (score 2):

It sort of looks like a cartoon dialogue curse word doesn't it?

Take it one symbol at a time. The `!` is boolean NOT, so if the following value is True it will become False, and vice versa.

The `$` starts a scalar value. `$@` is found in `man perlvar` and it is the error value output from the last `eval` call.